# CSV File creation affected by regionnal setting

Tags: csv

I create csv file from my web app and when the web app runs in my system with browser language set to English the file gets downloaded and on open shows the expected format. But when i change my language to Danish it shows like below !

[Wrong csv file format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xonWh.png)

The correct format should be like this

[image: Correct csv file format]

How do i correct this so that irrespective of the language the language the file csv file gets downloded properly ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the components you use to create, download, and display the .csv; so this may not help.

In general, language settings may specify the separator used for .csv files. If you can generate the .csv using tab as separator (TabDelimited), there is a chance that the .csv is parsed correctly regardless of the language settings.

Some .csv drivers/providers look into a schema.ini file in the folder containing the .csv file. By specifying the format (Format=Delimited()), you may help the driver to do the right thing.